# How to check node_modules folder is there or not in my angular project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, angular6, angular7

I am trying to check node_modules folder is there or not in my angular2 project using nodejs but facing struggle. I am new in nodejs So I do not know how to do it. Anybody can help me?

Note : ps -> project name

You can also check angular 2 project foldere structure: https://tutorialslink.com/Article_img/Blog_image/689d5f69-71b5-462e-8809-121fa9fd96bc.png

```
const fullPath = path.dirname("c://mamp/htdocs/projects/ps/src/app/app.component.html");
const regexResp = /^(.*?)node_modules/.exec(fullPath);
const nodemodulesPath = regexResp ? regexResp[1] : fullPath;
console.log(nodemodulesPath );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the fs(filesystem) module of nodejs

```
    const fs = require('fs');
// fs.statSync(path) method returns the instance of fs.Stats
try {
    const stats = fs.statSync("c://mamp/htdocs/projects/ps/node_modules");
    // stats.isDirectory() returns true if file path is Directory, otherwise returns false.
console.log('is directory ? ' + stats.isDirectory());
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Could not find node modules")
  }
```

Read more about this module here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Can you test this code inside vs code extension exports.activate = context => {  const fullPath = path.dirname("c://mamp/htdocs/projects/ps/src/app/app.component.html");
const regexResp = /^(.*?)node_modules/.exec(fullPath);
const nodemodulesPath = regexResp ? regexResp[1] : fullPath;
console.log(nodemodulesPath );   }

Comment: Which VS code extension do you want me to test this code ?